# Use ResourceDictionary from Windows.UI.Xaml namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces, vsix

I am trying to use the ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries property from Namespace Windows.UI.Xaml on my existing project, but I already have the ResourceDictionary from System.Windows.ResourceDictionary. I cannot figure out how can I use the one from Windows.UI.Xaml, so that I can have the ThemeDictionaries.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10nwc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO9wf.png)

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that `ThemeDictionaries` and the `ResourceDictionary` in the `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace is a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) thing that is not applicable to WPF.

A WPF `ResourceDictionary` and a UWP `ResourceDictionary` are not the same thing. They are not interchangeable, i.e. you cannot reuse them in both WPF and UWP apps.

Comment: I understand now... then do you have any ideas how can I apply one Image based on the theme of the IDE? (talking about VS extensions). I have the question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76172356/change-image-gif-based-on-the-vs-ide-theme

Thanks alot!

Comment: Or, am I missunderstanding the vsix project?

Comment: I am not sure how a VSIX project is related to resource dictionaries and theme resources.